# Plus or Minus (Square Root)

Tags: limits, radicals

I was evaluating

$$\lim _{(x,y,z) \to (2,8,1)} \sqrt{xy} \tan \frac {3 \pi z} 4$$

and got as far as $\sqrt 4 \cdot (-1)$. Now, how do I know if it is a positive or negative root besides graphing it (if you can)?

Comment: sqrt is *defined* as the nonnegative choice.

Comment: However note it would be $\sqrt{2\cdot 8}=\sqrt{16}$ at that point, not $\sqrt{4}.$ So (with the $-1$ from the tangent part), the overall answer would be $-4.$

Comment: Thank you. Sorry it was 16 not 4.